# Response to be Captured at Multiple Steps

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, sap-fiori, sap-srm

I am currently testing a functionality which is built on **SAP SRM with Fiori as its frontend**, for which I need some support

**Testing Tool** - MF Load Runner
**Protocol** - SAP-Web

**Test Case**

After the initial login into the system, we need to Create an invoice in the system which will generate an excel. Need to download the same and alter with few document specific data.
After the data is modified, the excel needs to be uploaded again, which will automatically trigger save action.
At this point, we need to measure the time taken to upload excel and the time taken to save the document.
Follwed by this, i need to trigger the next step for calculation of few values which is a async process and its completion is only informed by a notification on the Fiori screen of the application.

After the calculation is done, i need to perform an another step. the completion of that step is also notified only by a notification.

We have tried by **Ajax TruClient protocol** as well, but it didn't worked out.

I am able to download the excel and save it locally but not able to edit the data. Any alteration of the data with the script is not happening.
Also, Can someone suggest any other method to capture the time taken at multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this architecturally.   You have Truclient which is a browser.   It is not a generic functional automation solution that exercises anything that is not a browser.  You need to operate two apps, Excel and a Browser, so you need to move up the stack.

Don't time the stuff in Excel.  This is 100% client based.

You have three options if you absolutely under every circumstance must run excel.

- GUI Virtual User.   This is a full blown automation client.  In the Microfocus universe, this is QuickTest Pro.   I can automate your browser.  It can automate your excel.   It can automate your Powerpoint.  It can even automate solitaire.   You will need a single full OS instance to run this
- Citrix Virtual User.  If you head this route you have options.  You have Microfocus, Tricentis, Login VSI, and perhaps a handful of smaller players
- Remote Desktop Virtual User.  Similar to Citrix but fewer players.  Microfocus is the Dominant solution.

If you leave the absolute non volatile requirement to run excel behind, then you can have a pre-prepared modified excel file for upload that represents the "changed" document and run this purely as an HTTP virtual user.   TruClient is not going to operate your Windows Common Dialog Box (again, not a Browser) to allow you to pick a file.